# How to configure CPU utilized metric for ECS in AWS for Alarm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I wanted to have CPU Cloudwatch Alarm for my ECS service previously i used to use CPU Utilization metric which was in percentage i used to  give >80%. Seems they have removed it.[AWs Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-metrics-ECS.html)

So now we have CPUUtililized. I want to know how to configure it for 80%.
Its coming in 100s i had 4vCPU for my container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU Utilization is absolutely [still there](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/available_cloudwatch_metrics.html#ecs-metrics). It is part of the [basic metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/available_cloudwatch_metrics.html) always reported by ECS to CloudWatch.

The documentation page you linked is for ECS Container Insights, which is an option you have to enable on your ECS cluster for an added fee. When enabled, ECS Container Insights reports additional metrics to CloudWatch.

Comment: Yes! I was using namespace ECS/ContinerInsights and not ECS. Thanks